# @cypress/code-coverage Can't resolve '../self-coverage-helper' @cypress

Tags: cypress, nyc

I try to run in `index.js` of Cypress:

```
require('@cypress/code-coverage/task')
```

Getting this error:

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../self-coverage-helper' in 'C:\repo\patientstrength_codecover\node_modules\@cypress\code-coverage\node_modules\nyc'
```

Totally lost here. My `package.json`:

```
"nyc": "^15.1.0",
"cypress": "^5.0.0",
"cypress-istanbul": "^1.3.0",
"cypress-localstorage-commands": "^1.2.2",
"cypress-multi-reporters": "^1.2.4",
"@cypress/code-coverage": "^3.8.1",
"@babel/core": "^7.11.4",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.8.3",
"@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.10.4",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.0",
"@babel/preset-react": "^7.10.4",
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: not yet, so guess you are having the same issue?

Comment: Well I tried to radical downgrade cypress to version 4.6 and got this error: 
Error: Cannot find module '../self-coverage-helper' from 'C:\repo\patientstrength_dev\node_modules\@cypress\code-coverage\node_modules\nyc' but really cant find this module

Comment: Any updates on this?

Comment: Yeah I could fix it. The issue was that we are using a "root" package.json with basic scripts like gulp, jest and well - also we tried cypress. So we have a /git/root/package.json  & /git/root/solution1/package.json  & /git/root/solution2/package.json     We solved the issue by simply install cypress and all dependencies first (!) in the  /git/root/solution1/package.json & /git/root/solution2/package.json solutions. NOT in the /git/root/package.json. The /git/root/package.json now only contains a script invoking the 2 cypress installations. And later we merge the results. Sure some redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that we are using a "root" package.json with basic scripts like `gulp`, `jest` and well - also we tried to run Cypress from that root. And beside the coverage, it worked fine.

So we have:

- `/git/root/package.json`
- `/git/root/solution1/package.json`
- `/git/root/solution2/package.json`

We solved the issue by simply install Cypress and all dependencies first (!) in the:
`/git/root/solution1/package.json` and `/git/root/solution2/package.json` solutions.

NOT in the `/git/root/package.json`.

The `/git/root/package.json` now only contains a script invoking the 2 Cypress installations. And later we merge the results. Sure some redundancy

The invoke script is as following:

```
"test:client1": "cd client1 && cd ClientApp && npm run coverage"
```

So very simple approach. What we couldn't solve is the redundancy regarding Cypress configuration and commands. That can be optimized.